# Migrate onchange methods code from V7 to V8

Tags: odoo, openerp-8, odoo-8

I want to migrate product_id_change method of sale order line which is in version 7 to version 8 with new api.

Generally I seen we can't convert those onchange method in new api whose base method are written in old api, it will create issue while we calling base method with super.

I am getting error while doing this, error says you have passed 15 parameters to the method while 19 required.

```
def product_id_change( self, cr, uid, ids, pricelist, product, qty=0, uom=False, qty_uos=0, uos=False, name='', partner_id=False,
        lang=False, update_tax=True, date_order=False, packaging=False, fiscal_position=False, flag=False, context = None ):
```

This is the declaration of method with old api. I want to keep this code completely in new api with super method calling.

Is there any hope to achieve this ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can Migrate to version 8 this way

```
@api.multi
@api.onchange('product_id')
def product_id_change(self):
    if not self.product_id:
        return {'domain': {'product_uom': []}}

    vals = {}
    domain = {'product_uom': [('category_id', '=', self.product_id.uom_id.category_id.id)]}
    if not (self.product_uom and (self.product_id.uom_id.category_id.id == self.product_uom.category_id.id)):
        vals['product_uom'] = self.product_id.uom_id

    product = self.product_id.with_context(
        lang=self.order_id.partner_id.lang,
        partner=self.order_id.partner_id.id,
        quantity=self.product_uom_qty,
        date=self.order_id.date_order,
        pricelist=self.order_id.pricelist_id.id,
        uom=self.product_uom.id
    )

    name = product.name_get()[0][1]
    if product.description_sale:
        name += '\n' + product.description_sale
    vals['name'] = name

    if self.order_id.pricelist_id and self.order_id.partner_id:
        vals['price_unit'] = product.price
    self.update(vals)
    return {'domain': domain}
```